# javascript xml saving problem

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to modify some data on XML file residing on server side by using javascript.

I'm using following code

```
var xh;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xh=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xh=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xh.open("get","books.xml",false);
xh.send("");
var xdoc=xh.responseXML;
var x=xdoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
x[0].getAttributeNode("lang").nodeValue="zh";
xh.save("books.xml");
```

but its not working

Thanks in advance,
Guru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t edit files on a server using JavaScript (unless your server is running Node.js, but that’s a whole different story). JavaScript is a client-side language; you’ll need a server-side language if you want to write to a file.

Comment: thanks for your answer mathias,
but could you please make clear few things.

I just want to know that when javascript is not able to save xml files then why there are options like "xNode.nodeValue="xyz";"?

It could be read only too.

thanks,
:)

Comment: You can load an XML file into memory, parse its contents, and even change values etc. — but that’s just in memory. To change the actual file, you need a server-side script.